# Webdriver- Java- TestNGHow can I mark the test as Fail after running all Classes

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

So, I am using Selenium Webdriver-Java.

I have four files

**Setup.java** Where I set up the selenium server and Firefox browser and stop them.

**login.java**: class for test some css properties in the log in page

**Logout.java**: class for testing Log out

**Main.java** Where I call the Setup.java,login.java and logout.java

---

I use softassert method in the classes Login and Logout, Like

```
SoftAssert s_assert = new SoftAssert();
s_assert.assertEquals(fontSize, "13px", "BANNER Font size Test");
```

I have many softassertions in the file and I do a

```
s_assert.assertAll();
```

to mark it as failed in the TestNG report

- The problem is, if any assertion fails in the Login class, then Logout class is not executed. Is there a way to do 
  s_assert.assertAll(); in the main class where I call all the functions under @test ?

Thanks in advance!

Shario

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create String variable to carry message in class.

e.g.
`String errorMessages = null;`

Catch assertion error using Try catch block and store error message in variable.

```
try{
SoftAssert s_assert = new SoftAssert();
s_assert.assertEquals(fontSize, "13px", "BANNER Font size Test");
}catch(AssertionError ae){
if(errorMessages == null) errorMessgaes = "";
errorMessages += ae.getMessage();
}
//Code to execute logout
```

And throw it once you log out.

```
throw new Exception(yourStringVariable);
```

This way you can notify TestNG about error and it will mark your Test as failed.

hope it helps.